# Membership как узнать connectionStringName?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

MVS 2010 
Где узнать имя поставщика которое надо указывать в connectionStringName?
При AspNetSqlProvider выдаёт ошибку:

> Имя соединения 'AspNetSqlProvider' не было найдено в конфигурации
>   приложений или строка соединения пуста. (F:\autopass\web.config line
>   12)

Comment: вам необходимо настроить провайдер а не конекшен, прочитать можно тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6e9y4s5t(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Как его настроить то?

Comment: Так в описании же написано как. Необходимо просто внимательно прочитать, с первой строчки и до последней

Comment: мда, первый абзац содержит упоминание *Web Site Administration Tool* инструмент который позволяет не править `Web.Config` ручками. Далее по тексту есть ссылка на пошаговое руководство использования этого инструмента https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/879kf95c(v=vs.100).aspx или вы хотите, чтоб за вас все настроили?

Comment: connectionStringName=LocalSqlServer

Comment: @LEgXr оформите как ответ?